# How to convert numbers from file with strings to integer in a list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file which contains both names and numbers but I don't know how to convert the numbers to integers because they are on the same line with a string. I also want to sort it with the numbers.

This is like a scoreboard system and I want to print the top 5 player's scores and their names. Their scores are appended to a text file after they play a game which is read. The text file will have many more player's scores and names.

the file looks like this (we will call it data.txt):

```
Jack, 14
Amy, 2
Rock, 58
Jammy, 44
```

Once read, this is what the list looks like:

```
['Jack, 14', 'Amy, 2', 'Rock, 58', 'Jammy, 44']
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
file = open("data.txt", "r")
Data = file.readlines()
Data = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in Data]
```

I have tried these:

```
Data.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

Data = list(map(int, Data))
```

However, it shows an error because there is also a string on the same line which I don't want to be converted to an integer.

What I'm hoping to be output is:

```
Amy, 2
Jack, 14
Jammy, 44
Rock, 58
```

I just want to know how to sort by the numbers (scores) in ascending order with a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following *key* when sorting:

```
data = ['Jack, 14', 'Amy, 2', 'Rock, 58', 'Jammy, 44']
data.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.split(',')[1].strip()))
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
['Amy, 2', 'Jack, 14', 'Jammy, 44', 'Rock, 58']
```

The idea is to split the string on `','` then remove any trailing whitespace from the second element and convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to store the names and scores in pairs rather than as a string

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig
sorted_pairs = sorted(((pair[0], int(pair[1])) for pair in (line.split(', ') for line in file.readlines())), key = ig(0))
```